# Transform Hot Encoding

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, transform, one-hot-encoding

I have this data;

```
ID   Month
001  June
001  July
001  August
002  July
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
ID   June  July  August
001   1     1      1
002   0     1      0
```

I have tried one-hot encoding, my query is like this:

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(frame['month'])
frame = frame.drop('Month',axis = 1)
frame = frame.join(one_hot)
```

However, the result is like this

```
ID   June  July  August
001   1     0      0
001   0     1      0
001   0     0      1
002   0     1      0
```

May I know which part of my query is wrong?

Comment: What you desired is not *one-hot encoding*, which as name implies have one high bit (`1`) per row

Comment: What is expected ouput if first `July` is changed to `June` ?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) returns strictly 1-hot encoded values, you can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
>>> out = pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Month)
>>> out

Month  August  July  June
ID
1           1     1     1
2           0     1     0
```

To preserve the order of appearance of Months, you can `reindex`:

```
>>> out.reindex(df.Month.unique(), axis=1)

Month  June  July  August
ID
1         1     1       1
2         0     1       0
```

---

In case an ID can have more than 1 month associated with it *and* you want to see it as 1:

```
out = out.ne(0).astype(int)
```

can be used afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure OP need counts?

Comment: Not sure but I suspect so as they attempted `get_dummies` and ID-Month pairs seem unique. added a workaround.

Comment: ya, hot encodig return `0,1`, so `crosstab` here is bad idea (but if use out.ne(0).astype(int) it working, but in my opinion overcomplicated)

Answer (score 0):

If need hot encoding convert `ID` to index and aggregate `max` for always `0,1` ouput:

```
one_hot = (pd.get_dummies(frame.set_index('ID')['Month'])
             .max(level=0)
             .reindex(df.Month.unique(), axis=1))
print (one_hot)
    June  July  August
ID                    
1      1     1       1
2      0     1       0
```